# Check for generic parameter, wether it is in Type[] or not?

Tags: c#, generics

I have something like this:

```
public byte[] resultA<T>(string some, T myCustomGenericParameter) 
{
    Type[] typList = GetAllTypesFromAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile("aaaa.dddd.dll"));

    // checking wether my custom parameter is in "typList"
    typList.OfType<myCustomGenericParameter>().Any()
}
```

And I would like to check wether my generic parameter is in `typList`, but I get `Error 1   The type or namespace name 'myCustomGenericParameter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but do you mean `typList.Contains(typeof(T))`?  Is `myCustomGenericParameter` supposed to be a _type_?

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing that the type is in the list?  What are you doing with it?

Comment: Yes, `myCustomGenericParameter` is a type(a class), which should be in `typeList` and I want to check this.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking - is `myCustomGenericParameter` an instance of the `Type` class, or do you want to know if the _type of_ the object is in the collection?

Comment: Yes, it's an instance. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the difference.  What does `myCustomGenericParameter.GetType().ToString()` return?

Comment: it gives me a class name

Comment: Then it's not a `Type`, so either `typeof(T)` or `myCustomGenericParameter.GetType()` is what you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to check whether my generic parameter is in `typList`

Then just use

```
typeList.Contains(typeof(T));
```

or

```
typeList.Contains(myCustomGenericParameter.GetType());
```

if `myCustomGenericParameter` may be a subtype of `T` and you want to look for that specific type.

Note that `typList.OfType<T>` is not very helpful here since all of the objects in the collection are `Type` objects, so `OfType` doesn't really distinguish between them.  `OfType` is effective when applied to a collection that has objects of different types.